# In Laravel does artisan config:cache actually cache the config as specified in the cache.php settings?

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I have set up Laravel to use Redis as the cache.  I can verify that it is working when I use the `Cache::('my_var', 'my_val');` then inspecting Redis via the CLI to see that the key already been created.

My question is, after caching the Laravel config with `artisan config:cache` should I expect to see some entries in Redis since I've set up Laravel to use Redis as the cache?

I currently didn't do it yet, so I'm still wondering if something is configured wrong (and it's caching the config in a file in storage). Or if the actual config already been cached in PHP memory or something so, I shouldn't expect entries in Redis after caching the config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `php artisan config:cache`, a static PHP file will be generated on `bootstrap\cache\config.php` that returns all configs as an array. So the answer to

> should I expect to see some entries in redis since I've set up Laravel to use redis as the cache?

is NO, the Laravel won't use your cache driver to cache configs.

Comment: Thank you! It would be nice if the Laravel documentation more clearly explained this. I guess it says [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#configuration-caching) that the artisan command just combines the files, but the use of the term "cache" for both (completely unrelated?) things makes it confusing.